# Epson TM-T88IV installation issues Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

I am trying to install the Epson TM-T88IV in a Windows 7 x64 laptop.

The printer has a RS232 port, so i bought an adapter to USB so i can plug-in to the laptop.

I installed the drivers of the printer and the adapter, but i cannot send nothing to the printer.

Any advice, so i can put the printer working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some USB to RS232 adapters have issues.  While the OS may see the device, it has issues sending data.  We have found this for several brands we have tried.  Some work, some do not depending on the attached device.  This  [Startech Pro USB-Serial](http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/Professional-USB-to-RS-232-Serial-Adapter~ICUSB2321X) worked in most cases for us.

Have you confirmed all serial transmission settings as well?

Comment: Solved with a similar cable.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel connection is easily replaced with a USB connection in the printer itself. The replacement part costs less than $60 (US) and is available online. Getting the proper connection made my installation go from headache to a Tropical Breeze... just in time for opening day!
Look for part UB-U05